# How do I create a custom slideshow as a background?

Tags: desktop-background

When you ask to change the background of the desktop has a folder called contents that shows a sequence of slides. How do I create more sequences of slides with my own wallpaper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DesktopNova is ones for changing background with some specified folder.
To install desktopnova, Visit  https://launchpad.net/desktopnova/+download

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get [CREBS](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/create-background-slideshows-crebs-ubuntu-10-0410-10-maverick-meerkat/).  I had some trouble with desktopnova but crebs worked fine.