# How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow in Oneiric?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, desktop-background, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

None of the solutions listed in these two questions...

[How do I create a desktop wallpaper slideshow?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134/how-do-i-create-a-desktop-wallpaper-slideshow)

[How do I create a custom slideshow as a background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44361/how-do-i-create-a-custom-slideshow-as-a-background)

...have been updated for GNOME 3. Is it possible to create a slideshow with a XML in Oneiric?

Comment: I've tagged a bounty on that question to get it updated for GNOME3